# Is polling for a lock a correct way to implement critical sections?

Tags: c, locking, critical-section

If I have a critical section, I must implement a method of locking it. I saw the following variant:

```
while(lock)
{
    //do nothing
}
lock = true;
// code of critical section
lock = false;
```

However, I'm suspicious about it because in theory, several threads can perform `while(lock)` (check and see that it's = false), and get into critical section together because `while(lock)` and `lock = true;` are performed not in one continuous block. Am I wrong? Or this is indeed a not safe method?

Comment: You need a lock, so use a lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "almost safe", i.e. not safe at all. What it's lacking is exactly what you are seeing - multiple threads could see `lock == false` and enter the critical section. It needs an atomic operation, which must be supported by the hardware - a way to guarantee that only one thread of execution can acquire the lock.

That said, if the system you're writing can survive mutual exclusion failure, and be ok with working usually with occasional failures (perhaps logging or something where the occasional mangled entry wouldn't necessarily cause total failure), this pattern could "sorta" work...

Comment: "It needs an atomic operation, which must be supported by the hardware" - this should be an instruction in, say, assembly code, or there are ready mechanisms for that?

Comment: It's an instruction (or one of several) in the CPU's instruction set. It can be accessed via raw assembly code, or inline assembly code if your compiler supports such constructs. Better would be utilizing the threading/concurrency libraries that already have the right routines written, but you didn't mention whether this is Linux with gcc or Windows with VC++ or something else...

Comment: Ok, thank you, will dig into that. I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio C++ Builder 2010.

Answer (score 5):

You're correct -- it's not safe. Not much more to say than that.

Edit: No, there really, truly isn't much more to say about this construct. This is *not* a spin lock, nor is it much like a spin lock. For a spin lock, you need something vaguely like this:

```
// note: incomplete, not reentrant, not intended for real use
atomic_type spin_lock = 0;

// enter the spin lock:
int prev_value;

while ((prev_value = test_and_set(&spin_lock, 1)) != 0 || spin_lock != 1)
    ;
// code of critical section

// release the spin lock:
test_and_set(&spin_lock, 0);
```

The important point here is that to enter the spin lock, you need to obtain the previous value and set the new value *atomically*. Then you have to verify that *your* write to the lock changed it from "not-owned" to "owned" status.

Comment: You are correct, too, but only for the first sentence. There is much more to say.

Comment: @JensGustedt: There's certainly a lot more to say about thread-safe programming (and such), but not much more to say about this particular construct.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is called a spinlock. The new C standard, C11, implements a primitive datatype called `atomic_flag` that can be used like that. Almost all modern hardware supports it but unfortunately most compilers are not yet exactly there to support it on the level on the syntax, but have their own extensions. E.g gcc has builtins `__sync_lock_test_and_set` and `__sync_lock_release` for this.

Comment: This isn't a spin lock, nor even much like a spin lock.